# Am I a pest for asking a journal repeatedly for submission updates?

Tags: publishing

I submitted an undergraduate research paper back in early Fall of 2018. About 6 or 7 months later in Spring 2019 I asked for an update and got the reviewers report soon thereafter.  The reviewer said they would recommend it for acceptance pending minor, mostly typographic changes. I made the necessary changes and resubmitted around July.

I hadn't heard back by the end of November, double the average time from submission to acceptance for this particular journal, so I asked about the status again. I was told by the editor-in-chief that he checked in with the referee and should be able to send the acceptance within the next day or two.

That was last month and I still haven't got any formal acceptance. Should I contact them again or am I just being overly concerned and impatient?

Comment: Some journals have long publication backlogs, and editors are not focused on papers that got positive reviews asking for minor revisions because they are usually unproblematic. Keep reminding them, but don't expect swift publication even after they accept.